# How do I get the code in jsfiddle to work in my Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, jsfiddle

```js
const canvasEle = document.getElementById('drawing-container');
const canvasPad = document.getElementById('pad');
const toolbar = document.getElementById('toolbar');
const context = canvasEle.getContext('2d');
const padContext = canvasPad.getContext('2d');

const canvasOffsetX = canvas.offsetLeft;
const canvasOffsetY = canvas.offsetTop;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth - canvasOffsetX;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - canvasOffsetY;

let startPosition = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
let lineCoordinates = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
let isDrawStart = false;

const getClientOffset = (event) => {
  const {
    pageX,
    pageY
  } = event.touches ? event.touches[0] : event;
  const x = pageX - canvasPad.offsetLeft;
  const y = pageY - canvasPad.offsetTop;

  return {
    x,
    y
  }
}

toolbar.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.id === 'clear') {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
});

toolbar.addEventListener('change', e => {
    if(e.target.id === 'stroke') {
        ctx.strokeStyle = e.target.value;
    }

    if(e.target.id === 'lineWidth') {
        lineWidth = e.target.value;
    }
    
});

const drawLine = (ctx) => {
  if (!isDrawStart) {
    return;
  }
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startPosition.x, startPosition.y);
  ctx.lineTo(lineCoordinates.x, lineCoordinates.y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

const mouseDownListener = (event) => {
  startPosition = getClientOffset(event);
  isDrawStart = true;
}

const mouseMoveListener = (event) => {
  if (!isDrawStart) return;

  lineCoordinates = getClientOffset(event);
  clearCanvas(padContext);
  drawLine(padContext);
}

const mouseupListener = (event) => {
  clearCanvas(padContext);
  drawLine(context);
  isDrawStart = false;
}

const clearCanvas = (ctx) => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasEle.width, canvasEle.height);
}

canvasPad.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownListener);
canvasPad.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveListener);
canvasPad.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseupListener);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
}

h1 {
    background: #7F7FD5;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #91EAE4, #86A8E7, #7F7FD5);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #91EAE4, #86A8E7, #7F7FD5);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
  
  .cnv-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .pad {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    border: 4px solid #333;
  }

  .container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

#toolbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 70px;
    background-color: #202020;
}

#toolbar * {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

#toolbar label {
    font-size: 12px;
}

#toolbar input {
    width: 100%;
}

#toolbar button {
    background-color: #1565c0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color:white;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE = edge">
            <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device - width, initial - scale = 0.1">
            <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "styles.css">
            <title> Pipe Illustrator </title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <section class  = "container">
                <div id = "toolbar">
                    <h1>Draw.</h1>
                    <label for="stroke">Stroke</label>
                    <input id="stroke" name='stroke' type="color">
                    <label for="lineWidth">Line Width</label>
                    <input id="lineWidth" name='lineWidth' type="number" value="5">
                    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
                </div>
                <div class = "drawing-container">
                    <canvas id = "drawing-container"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class = "cnv-wrapper">
                    <canvas id = "cnv-wrapper"></canvas>
                </div>
            </section>
            <script src = "./index.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

The project is to make a simple line drawer which makes allows me to draw fixed straight lines without the previous line being removed. The code written below is exactly what I need and was provided by another user from a question I asked previously about making it as my code wouldn't allow for the previous line to remain when drawing a new one.

This is the code below which is in jsfiddle, when I copy and paste it into my Visual studio code, I don't get the same output as I would in jsfiddle, the canvas doesn't appear nor does it allow anything to be drawn. Am I missing something ?

Right so this is the code i have written in VSC. It isn't entirely what was in the jsfiddle, i tried to integrate some other functions from another paint project i did. I was trying to add a toolbar for line colour and width. I think the way i have written it is contradicting it all got quite messy and was quite a fail. These are projects im doing to learn code as i am still a beginner to coding. Thank you for your help and input.

```js
const canvasEle = document.querySelector('.draw-container');
const canvasPad = document.querySelector('.pad');
const context = canvasEle.getContext('2d');
const padContext = canvasPad.getContext('2d');
let startPosition = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
let lineCoordinates = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
let isDrawStart = false;

const getClientOffset = (event) => {
  const {
    pageX,
    pageY
  } = event.touches ? event.touches[0] : event;
  const x = pageX - canvasPad.offsetLeft;
  const y = pageY - canvasPad.offsetTop;

  return {
    x,
    y
  }
}

const drawLine = (ctx) => {
  if (!isDrawStart) {
    return;
  }
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startPosition.x, startPosition.y);
  ctx.lineTo(lineCoordinates.x, lineCoordinates.y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

const mouseDownListener = (event) => {
  startPosition = getClientOffset(event);
  isDrawStart = true;
}

const mouseMoveListener = (event) => {
  if (!isDrawStart) return;

  lineCoordinates = getClientOffset(event);
  clearCanvas(padContext);
  drawLine(padContext);
}

const mouseupListener = (event) => {
  clearCanvas(padContext);
  drawLine(context);
  isDrawStart = false;
}

const clearCanvas = (ctx) => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasEle.width, canvasEle.height);
}

canvasPad.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownListener);
canvasPad.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveListener);
canvasPad.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseupListener);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.cnv-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.pad {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.draw-container {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="cnv-wrapper">
  <canvas class="draw-container" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  <canvas class="pad" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you use `script` tags?

Comment: That JavaScript is designed to run in a web browser. VS Code is not a web browser. You can't run that code in a VS Code extension. You might configure VS Code to launch it in a web browser. You might configure VS Code to launch it in Node.js (where it would fail because Node.js is not a web browser). It isn't remotely clear what you have done between "copy and pasting the code" and "not seeing the rendered canvas". Please read [ask].

Comment: @GetSet yea i tried adding them in and still nothing

Comment: @Quentin I copied the javascript code as it lies in jsfiddle and pasted it in a new index.js file in VSC and again for the HTML and CSS code and it all sits in one file. Once all saved, I opened the index.html file in chrome and the canvas did not show up how it should. So from what you're saying the code isn't written for it to work in VSC, do you have any advice on converting it so it will?

Comment: It's not a VSC issue. You can't just copy and paste code without also using the appropriate html tags. Your CSS needs to go in `style` tags. Your scripts need to go in `script` tags. The dom elements, e.g. the "canvas" needs to go in the `body` tag. Etc. ... You may also need to affix the appropriate "doctype" and you may need to trigger the scripts to run on document load.

Comment: You can tell us what you did all you want, without actual seeing what you did nobody can help you find why it doesn't work... also the HTML code at jsfiddle doesn't show you the actual code of the page, like header and where the javascript is included. so my guess that's where your problem is. You got to tell HTML where your css and js files are. For a quick test, you could simply combine all 3 files into one instead. by using `<style>` and `<script>` tags in html

Comment: @GetSet i will update the code above and show what i have written in VSC

Comment: @garbanz0 — If you are opening it in Chrome then you are running it in Chrome and not in VS Code!

Comment: The problem seems to be that you didn't include the boilerplate that JS Fiddle doesn't show you. Like the `<script>` tags. You should take an introductory JS tutorial (like the one at MDN) instead of trying to learn the basics by copy/pasting people's demo code.

Comment: @Quentin yes, if you want to be technical, however VSC allows debug from the browser *it* launches.

Comment: @vanowm — Yes, it does, and I mentioned that the OP might be launching it in a web browser in my original comment. That isn't what the OP said they were doing through. They just said "Once all saved, I opened the index.html file in chrome".

Comment: @Quentin to see the output i have to open it in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

From comments where I advise:

You can't just copy and paste code [from fiddle] without also using the appropriate html tags. Your CSS needs to go in `style` tags. Your scripts need to go in `script` tags. The dom elements, e.g. the "canvas" needs to go in the `body` tag. Etc. ... You may also need to affix the appropriate "doctype" and you may need to trigger the scripts to run on document load.

As an example, I tried the pasted code using the above advice on my own computer and it worked.

I'll show the complete source and then followup with a runnable version here on SO. Note that the runnable version uses SO's utility for such and as such you won't see all the various tags I mentioned, but the functionality remains the same just as with the "fiddle".

**Corrected "pasted" source showing all the relevant tags you need to create:**

```
<!doctype html> <!-- Add appropriate doctype -->

<html>
<head>

<style>
/* Paste the CSS in a style tag */

body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.cnv-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.pad {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.draw-container {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
</style>

</head>

<body> 

<div class="cnv-wrapper">
  <canvas class="draw-container" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  <canvas class="pad" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
// Paste your init scripts into the onload event to ensure they get ran after the canvas is created

window.onload = function() {
    
    const canvasEle = document.querySelector('.draw-container');
    const canvasPad = document.querySelector('.pad');
    const context = canvasEle.getContext('2d');
    const padContext = canvasPad.getContext('2d');
    let startPosition = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    };
    let lineCoordinates = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    };
    let isDrawStart = false;

    const getClientOffset = (event) => {
      const {
        pageX,
        pageY
      } = event.touches ? event.touches[0] : event;
      const x = pageX - canvasPad.offsetLeft;
      const y = pageY - canvasPad.offsetTop;

      return {
        x,
        y
      }
    }

    const drawLine = (ctx) => {
      if (!isDrawStart) {
        return;
      }
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(startPosition.x, startPosition.y);
      ctx.lineTo(lineCoordinates.x, lineCoordinates.y);
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    const mouseDownListener = (event) => {
      startPosition = getClientOffset(event);
      isDrawStart = true;
    }

    const mouseMoveListener = (event) => {
      if (!isDrawStart) return;

      lineCoordinates = getClientOffset(event);
      clearCanvas(padContext);
      drawLine(padContext);
    }

    const mouseupListener = (event) => {
      clearCanvas(padContext);
      drawLine(context);
      isDrawStart = false;
    }

    const clearCanvas = (ctx) => {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasEle.width, canvasEle.height);
    }

    canvasPad.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownListener);
    canvasPad.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveListener);
    canvasPad.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseupListener); 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Now on to demonstrating this code works now here on SO.**

Note that SO's intepreter of code also (like "fiddle") doesn't need the tags mentioned that would be needed when you copy and paste into your own editor. Therefore I re-mention where the pasted code goes in code comments.

```js
// Your scripts will go in a <script> tag

// Use an onload event handler to ensure they get ran after the canvas is created

window.onload = function() {
    const canvasEle = document.querySelector('.draw-container');
    const canvasPad = document.querySelector('.pad');
    const context = canvasEle.getContext('2d');
    const padContext = canvasPad.getContext('2d');
    let startPosition = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    };
    let lineCoordinates = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    };
    let isDrawStart = false;

    const getClientOffset = (event) => {
      const {
        pageX,
        pageY
      } = event.touches ? event.touches[0] : event;
      const x = pageX - canvasPad.offsetLeft;
      const y = pageY - canvasPad.offsetTop;

      return {
        x,
        y
      }
    }

    const drawLine = (ctx) => {
      if (!isDrawStart) {
        return;
      }
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(startPosition.x, startPosition.y);
      ctx.lineTo(lineCoordinates.x, lineCoordinates.y);
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    const mouseDownListener = (event) => {
      startPosition = getClientOffset(event);
      isDrawStart = true;
    }

    const mouseMoveListener = (event) => {
      if (!isDrawStart) return;

      lineCoordinates = getClientOffset(event);
      clearCanvas(padContext);
      drawLine(padContext);
    }

    const mouseupListener = (event) => {
      clearCanvas(padContext);
      drawLine(context);
      isDrawStart = false;
    }

    const clearCanvas = (ctx) => {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasEle.width, canvasEle.height);
    }

    canvasPad.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownListener);
    canvasPad.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveListener);
    canvasPad.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseupListener); 
}
```

```css
/* Your CSS would go in a <style> tag */

body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.cnv-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.pad {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.draw-container {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<!-- Your HTML would go in the <body> tag -->

<div class="cnv-wrapper">
  <canvas class="draw-container" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  <canvas class="pad" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Right, thank you for showing me in further detail what you meant. After reading everyone's responses I think maybe I should stop these projects and go back to learning code basics; as it is very much clear I'm not as grasped as you guys are. Any advice on a good place to begin?

Comment: I'd recommend keeping on the track you are on. Now that you know how to get those "fiddles" to work on your own computer, experiment with them. Change some numbers and see what happens. E.g. what happens if you change the canvas's width from 500 to 100? This is how you learn.

Comment: Okay, i'll give that a try, thank you :)